# React-Native Expo FileSystem.getInfoAsync modifies the files before returning?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I created a React-Native application using Expo. When I make a call to [FileSystem.getInfoAsync](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/filesystem/#filesystemgetinfoasyncfileuri-options), all of the returned files have the same last modificationTime attached to them. Am I wrong in thinking that the value is the time they were last modified (as linked docs say)? It is behaving as though the files are being modified before being returned. They all have the same modification timestamp. I figured I would post here for some guidance before making a ticket with Expo, since I'm still new and it's very possible I've done something incorrectly.

In short, there is a directory of files in the application that I am working on that live within the application. They are log files of sorts, so they are only ever modified by certain events. After a file reaches a certain size, it is no longer written to but kept as means of history for awhile. As part of a cleanup process, when a new file needs to be created, it checks if the file limit has been reached. I wanted to use this timestamp to determine which file is the oldest and mark it for deletion.

Here are the relevant functions:

```
            export async function getInfoAsync(fileUri: string, options?: {}) {
                const opts: AllFileOptions = {
                    size: true,
                    ...options
                }
                return await FileSystem.getInfoAsync(fileUri, options);
            }
```

```
            export async function getDirFileInformation(path: string, list: string[]) {
                let dirInfoList = new Set<FileSystem.FileInfo>();
                for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
                    await getInfoAsync(path + "/" + list[0]).then(
                        (rsp) => {
                            if (rsp.exists) {
                                dirInfoList.add(rsp);
                            }
                        }
                    ).catch(
                        (err) => {
                            throw Error("getDirFileInformation: ", err);
                        }
                    )
                }

                return dirInfoList;
            }
```

```
            let dirInfoList = await getDirFileInformation(filePath, logs);
            let index = 0;
            dirInfoList.forEach((file) => {
                index++;
                console.log("File Modification Time for file # - " + index + ": ", file.modificationTime);
            })
```

Answer (score 1):

So... the problem was the hardcoded

```
await getInfoAsync(path + "/" + list[0]).then(
```

We had a power outage, and I made the assumption when it came back on that the code was where I had it before the outage. It was slightly rolled back to when I was doing some debugging.

Not a bad way to waste 2 hours of my life LOL.